# heroku pushing for deployment, something went wrong with my database, relation "users" doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to open heroku with my application but I"m looking at the logs and I see this error regarding my users database? I've tried to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and restarting heroku and stuff but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what these lines mean. Hopefully someone can help me out here?

```
 => Booting WEBrick
 => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:56009
 at=info method=GET path=/ host=upkeepin.herokuapp.com fwd="76.89.238.178" dyno=web.1 connect=20ms service=1539ms status=500 bytes=643
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
 ):

 LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                         ^
   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
 :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `exec_no_cache'
               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_re
```

Thanks

EDIT:

FOllowing the instructions below, I'm getting this now, after running `heroku logs`:

```
     10:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3270629977905203478_70215431754220'

   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (44.9ms)
     11:   
     12:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
     13:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
     15: <body>
   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (58.1ms)
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 179ms

 ActionView::Template::Error (gmaps4rails.css isn't precompiled):
     9:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

     14: </head>
```

Comment: It's look like that db not fully migrated

Comment: @bronislav do you have a solution on how I could get it fully migrated or what might be a cause of it not being migrated fully? Thanks

Comment: Can you show associations from your models and migrations that create tables? Probably you have an association in model, but don't have a migration for association.

Comment: @bronislav is there a simple way of showing my associations? Like is there some kind of console command like a `rake routes` type of command where it'll just pop up in my console and i can copy and paste it? I have a bunch and it'll seem like a headache if i displayed it.

Answer (score 4):

Do this

```
$ git push heroku
$ heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm <name-heroku-gave-to-your-app>
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku run rake db:populate
```

and then try this:

```
$ heroku restart
```

Comment: rake aborted when i did db:populate... i keep getting depreciation warning, don't know if that's part of the error? and it aborts after and says `don't know how to build task db:populate`

Comment: Kill it!

`heroku destroy`

then 

`heroku create

git push heroku master
heroku rakedb:migrate`

Just make sure you have the pg gem in your gemfile for production

`group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
`
and add config/database.yml to your .gitignore file too for good measure.

Comment: It says that I have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! for the depreciation warning. destroying the heroku app will fix this? Wouldn't it show up again?

Comment: I think this fix it, but if does not fix, try this:

`heroku run bash --app appname
rake db:migrate`

or

`heroku pg:reset DATABASE`
`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: `vendor/plugins` isn't the problem here, those are only warnins. It's `heroku run rake db:migrate`..

possibly just `heroku rake db:migrate` if you're not on the Cedar stack (note migrate, not migration)

Comment: i still get depreciation warning, but when i do db:migrate it looks like all my migration has been created

Comment: I'm getting a different error now that I just checked using `heroku logs`, is this something closer and easier to a solution? I've updated my OP

Comment: What warning in console, it your config your app wright you don't have any error. [Check this for more information](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not understanding what warning you're referring to?

Comment: It will compile the assets each request which is very slow. The best solution is add `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )` to `config/application.rb` and then run the `rake assets:precompile` and commit the compiled assets to your repository before pushing to Heroku. You’ll also want to modify the `config/development.rb` to change serve public assets to false otherwise you will get duplicate assets in development.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for helping me go through this. I've also posted a solution to my problem. It was because of my gmaps4rails.css that was causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

The error came from not being able to precompile my gmaps4rails and the answer lies in my other post here:

[rails heroku giving me We're sorry something went wrong error, gmaps4rails.css isn't compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479249/rails-heroku-giving-me-were-sorry-something-went-wrong-error-gmaps4rails-css-i#17479545)