# rails heroku giving me We're sorry something went wrong error, gmaps4rails.css isn't compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I checked my `heroku logs` and the only thing that I can see that's giving me errors is

```
2013-07-04T21:32:14.887388+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (gmaps4rails.css isn't precompiled):
```

and then a few lines down I get

```
2013-07-04T21:32:14.888116+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 767ms
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error but maybe if I fix this issue, I can test to see if I'm still getting the error. In my confi/application.rb file I have this:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.assets.precompile += %w( gmaps4rails.css )
config.assets.compile = true
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error.

Also, I've tried restarting my heroku server, using `heroku rake db:migrate` and still getting the same errors.

Thanks

EDIT:

Added output from `rake assets:precompile --trace`

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/andrewliu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /Users/andrewliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
```

Comment: Did you run `rails generate gmaps4rails:install`? as mentioned here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails#requirements

Comment: In poinf 4 below they readme says to add `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>` to layout instead of `config.assets.precompile += %w( gmaps4rails.css )` as you did

Comment: I have done generate gmaps and have added stylsheet in my application. THe gmaps4rails works in local.

Comment: It works locally because there's no asset compilation in development. Can you try `rake assets:precompile --trace`?

Comment: i just ran that and I edited my OP to show the output. Is there something in the output that can help with this issue?

Comment: Nope, it looks all ok. Did you add this line by hand? `config.assets.precompile += %w( gmaps4rails.css )`

Comment: Also do you have `gmaps4rails.css` in your `app/assets/stylesheets`?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Yeah I added it into my config/application. Also, I do have the gmaps4rails.css in my stylesheets folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comments above I think you should

1. Remove this line from enviroment

   `config.assets.precompile += %w( gmaps4rails.css )`
2. Remove this line from layout

   `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>`
3. Check if in `applications.css` you have this file included explicitly or `require_tree .`

because if you have `gmaps4rails.css` in `app/assets/stylesheets` then it should be precompiled with other assets.

EDIT: Explanation

What was the problem really? Two things.
First you ask Rails to add a file to asset compilation, but you should only do it if file is outside app/assets directory (ex. in gem)
Second, in layout you wanted to add a stylesheet link to this file but it was not compiled separately but as a part of `application.css`

Comment: What line are you talking about for #2?

Comment: Oh wow! it works! Now my app is running! Why did we need to delete stylesheet as well?

Comment: Edited to explain the problem in detail.